# How to do paired t-tests by group and save the results?

Tags: r

I had a time series data frame structured like this:

```r
>data
  ID  Location Sex   Time  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6
   12     A     M     .1    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .2    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .3    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .4    …      …     …     …     …     …
   12     A     M     .5    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .6    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .1    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .2    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .3    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .4    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .5    …      …     …     …     …     …
```

There were several hundred individuals, each having a unique ID number. There were several hundred measurements per individual. For instance in the example above there are only 6 observations for individual 12, and 5 observations for individual 234. In reality individual 12 may have 980 observations and individual 234 may have 1249 observations. `Var1:6` are measurements of the concentration of a substance at the corresponding time.

I want to make these comparisons for each `variable`: 
1. Is there a difference (in concentration) between the first observation per individual and the last observation per individual
2. Is there a difference between the first observation per individual, and the average of the first 7 observations per individual
3. Is there a difference between the last observation per individual, and the average of the last 7 observations per individual
4. Is there a difference between the average of the first seven observations per individual and the average of the last 7 observations per individual

So I subset/calculate all those observations for each individual and use `pivot_longer()` to structure my data frame like this:

```r
ID  Location  Sex  Variable  FirstPt  FirstPt7avg    LastPt     LastPt7avg
12     A        M      Var1     …           …            …           …
12     A        M      Var2     …           …            …           … 
12     A        M      Var3     …           …            …           …
12     A        M      Var4     …           …            …           …
12     A        M      Var5     …           …            …           …
12     A        M      Var6     …           …            …           …
234    A        M      Var1     …           …            …           …
234    A        M      Var2     …           …            …           …
234    A        M      Var3     …           …            …           …
234    A        M      Var4     …           …            …           …
234    A        M      Var5     …           …            …           …
234    A        M      Var6     …           …            …           …
```

Now I want to group the observations by `ID` and conduct a paired t.test for each variable. I have tried this but cannot get it to work:

```r
data%>%
group_by(ID)%>%
t.test(FirstPt, FirstPt7avg, paired = T)
```

What am I doing wrong? and what is the best way to save the results into a new data frame that shows where the differences were/were not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the p values for t-tests you can just do:

```r
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(ttest = t.test(FirstPt, FirstPt7avg, paired = T)$p.value)
```

For example, suppose I have

```r
> df
   ID     var1     var2
1   A 21.31678 20.52164
2   A 20.79443 20.15225
3   A 20.48503 21.15397
4   A 22.37103 23.25575
5   A 19.71829 20.64950
6   A 20.19900 22.32382
7   A 20.81024 22.11880
8   A 19.87774 22.64962
9   A 21.00772 22.68162
10  A 20.51758 24.51752
11  B 19.77003 22.30252
12  B 19.83237 21.33619
13  B 17.52396 22.06296
14  B 19.39885 20.81234
15  B 20.03151 21.57950
16  B 21.22612 21.25238
17  B 19.30079 21.87367
18  B 18.49585 20.98133
19  B 19.77482 19.16042
20  B 19.99106 23.51147
```

Then I can do

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(ttest = t.test(var1, var2)$p.value)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   ID       ttest
#   <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 A     0.0211  
# 2 B     0.000658
```